# How to calculate Standard deviation with mean 0 and Min and max value on x-axis is -1 and 1 respectively?

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation

How to calculate Standard deviation with mean 0 and Min and max value on x-axis is -1 and 1 respectively?
It is of-course a normalize distribution.

I apologize in advance for stupid question.

Comment: Do you mean how many deviations there are , in a standard normal, between 0,1 and 0,-1 ?

Comment: Yes, i think that is the formal way of asking it.Or will it be between  -1 and 1?

Comment: It is difficult to answer in the comments; let me post it as an answer.

Comment: Ok please post it in answer.Thanks.

Comment: Please let me know if that works. Still, don't worry, we have all asked stupid questions at some point or another. I definitely have.

Comment: if we change the standard deviation to 3 or 4 then how will this formula work?

Comment: Once you know the values of the mean $\mu$ and the standard deviation $\sigma$, the value of $z(x)$ automatically gives you the number of $\sigma$s from the mean. Say you have mean $1$ and deviation 3. Then any value $x$ will be $(x-1)/3$ deviations from the mean. This is precisely what $z(x)$ measures, by definition/construction.

Comment: For example: μ = 0 and σ = 5 but I still don't know x in this case?

Comment: But then what do you want to find out with that information?

Comment: I can ask this question as a separate question, but actaully I wanted to know this:  If I generate a normalized random number between -1 and 1 (mean is 0) with standard deviation 2 then this will mean that 68% numbers generated will be with in ______ interval. I want to ask how to calculate this interval?

Comment: The numbers would within 1 deviation of the mean, by the $68-95-99.7$ rule, so this interval would be (Approx.) $(-2,2)$. because this interval contains 1 deviation of the mean in each direction. If you want more details, I can include it below in my answer; please let me know. Please see my edit below, at the bottom.

Comment: Please see my edit at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the z-value $z(x)$ of $x=1$; the z-value measures precisely ( by definition) , the number of deviations of any value from the mean. In a standard normal, the mean is $0$, and the standard deviation is $1$. We then have : $$z(x)=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} $$ , which, in this case is equal to $$z(1)=\frac{1-0}{1}=1 $$ , so, in a standard normal, i.e., when $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$ , the value $1$ is exactly one deviation from the mean. By symmetry of the normal, there is also -1 deviations from the mean between $0$ and $-1$. So there is a total of 2 deviations from the mean between $-1$ and $1$ in a standard normal.

Notice that in any normal distribution; whether normal or not, the $68-95-99.7$ rule will apply, so that the intervals $(-\sigma, \sigma), (-2\sigma, 2\sigma), (-3\sigma, 3\sigma)$ will contain respectively $68%-95%-99.7%$ of all data.